# Virtual Box does not load VMs after upgrade

Tags: virtualbox

```
--------------------------- VirtualBox - Error In supR3HardenedWinReSpawn --------------------------- <html><b> (rc=-5640)</b><br/><br/>Please try reinstalling VirtualBox.<br><br><!--EOM-->where: supR3HardenedWinReSpawn what:  1 VERR_SUP_VP_THREAD_NOT_ALONE (-5640) - Process Verification Failure: The process has more than one threads.

+++
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu Client.

The virtual machine 'Ubuntu Client' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\hemant_s\VirtualBox VMs\Ubuntu Client\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}

+++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Hardening Log File-----------

dfc.39f8: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll)
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'mmdevapi.dll'...
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'mmdevapi.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\mmdevapi.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'msvcrt.dll'...
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'msvcrt.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'msvcrt.dll'...
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'msvcrt.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff913d00000 LB 0x0001c000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll [fFlags=0x0]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff9242b0000 LB 0x0000d000 C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [fFlags=0x0]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv (Input=msacm32.drv, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9242b0000 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.drv'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #0 'msvcrt.dll'.
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #12 'winmm.dll'.
dfc.39f8: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll)
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'winmm.dll'...
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'winmm.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\winmm.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\winmm.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'msvcrt.dll'...
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'msvcrt.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll (Input=midimap.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff921dd0000 LB 0x0000a000 C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll [fFlags=0x0]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff921dd0000 'C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll (Input=midimap.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff921dd0000 'C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll (Input=midimap.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff921dd0000 'C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll'
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\midimap.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll (Input=midimap.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000001001:<flags> [calling]
dfc.39f8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff921dd0000 'C:\Windows\System32\midimap.dll'
dfc.367c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\MMDevAPI.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
dfc.367c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=0000000000002009:<flags> [calling]
dfc.367c: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=00007ff9387a0000 'C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll'
dfc.2e5c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #0 'msvcrt.dll'.
dfc.2e5c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #23 'rpcrt4.dll'.
dfc.2e5c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #24 'oleaut32.dll'.
dfc.2e5c: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\edputil.dll)
dfc.2e5c: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\edputil.dll
dfc.2e5c: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   00007ff923510000 LB 0x00044000 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll [fFlags=0x0]
dfc.2e5c: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\edputil.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
42b8.459c: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 31106 ms, the end);
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

**Troubleshooting done so far:**

1. Restarted VB
2. Restarted Computer(Host)
3. Reinstalled VBox
4. Tried running in detachaable mode(it works, but Guest OSes Hang in some time)
5. Tried installing vboxdrv file multiple times.
6. Researched Oracle Virtual Box FAQ on hardening to no avail

**Version details:**

VirtualBox Graphical User Interface
Version 6.0.14 r133895 (Qt5.6.2)
Copyright © 2019 Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Comment: Do you have any anti-virus running on Windows host?  What version of Windows are you running and did the error start after you upgraded Windows or Vbox?

Comment: I am using Symantec. But have completely put all VM folkders in exceptions list. I am running Windows 10 Professional. 

The issue started after I upgraded from 5.2 to 6.0.14

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/269373/lx07

Comment: The VBox hardening is to protect the VBox programs on the host against .dll injection so you would need to exclude these not the VM guest folders.  You could try that ,or uninstalling Symantec, or `sfc /scannow`, or the other steps in [Diagnosing VirtualBox Hardening Issues](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=82106).  If none helps your question may get more viability on the [VirtualBox on Windows Hosts](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewforum.php?f=6) forum.  Don't forget to include your zipped *VBoxHardening.log* file.